# I want to convert my jquery code to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Jquery code is:

```
 $("#chatbtn").contents().find('#maximizeChat').on("click", function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     alert('clicked');
  });
```

I've tried this:

```
document.querySelector("#chatbtn").contents().querySelector('#maximizeChat').addEventListener("click", function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert('clicked');
});
```

Showing this error:

**(index):50 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: document.querySelector(...).contents is not a function**

How can I do this?

Comment: jQuery **is** JavaScript. It's a library.

Comment: You may remove contents in the JavaScript code, it is not required. You can query maximizeChart DOM directly in chatBtn parent.

Comment: I know. But I don't want to use jquery.

Comment: @vishnusandhireddy — It is required if there is an iframe involved

Comment: @mdpervez — You need to provide an [mcve] and ask a more specific question (e.g. "I'm trying to access the content of an iframe. If I were using jQuery I could use `contents()` but I'm not using that library. Here is my HTML and JS. This is my error message.)

Comment: Why is the question closed? It's a simple question that could be solved by simply reading the error message, but it is a valid question nonetheless and is incorrectly closed. Facts that jQuery is javascript library is true, but it does not take away from the question of transcribing jQuery to vanilla js, just like there already is a MVCR. If you enter the provided code, you will end up with the exact same error.

Answer (score 1):

`.contents()` on a frame returns the document within the frame. So, you're looking for: Access your frame and find the id:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('chatbtn');
var content = frame.contentDocument;

content.getElementById("maximizeChat").addEventListener("click",function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Comment: `contents` is usually used to access the content of an iframe. It is very unlikely that `maximizeChat` is in the current document.